# Bind key combinations to commands and suppress all others

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard

I'm trying to make my keyboard function a bit like a stenotype (but not). I want to bind combinations of keys to commands and ignore the standard individual key presses.

I am on GNU/Linux, using Xorg. I don't mind if the solution relies on Xorg.

Utilities like sxhkd and xbindkeys can bind key combinations to commands, capturing those events but I don't know how I could make them suppress everything beside the specified key combinations.

Does anyone know how I could do this? Could you point me in the right direction in Linux generally, a utility, or something in a programming language? I know shell scripting, Python, and I am just beginning to learn C. [This keyboard module](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard) for Python looked good but there's [currently no key suppression for Linux](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/issues/22) .

Comment: Hmm, it's likely possible with an ugly combination of xmodmap and sxhkd/xbindkeys. Xmodmap can truly rebind the keys, so you can rebind them to some bogus key that doesn't do anything (like XF86Send or something) and then use sxhkd/xbindkeys to run something when that key is pressed but it's gonna be convoluted and probably tricky to get it working right.

Comment: You should really look into hooking into some [input method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method) framework like XIM, IBus, SCIM, uim, etc though it's NOT for the faint of heart ;-) Of course, you can simply write your own xbindkeys-like X11 app which grabs the "prefix" keys passively (and then grab the whole keyboard, etc), but you will run into issues with dummy apps -- which unfortunately includes things like chromium ;-( -- reacting to `Notify{Grab,Ungrab}` focus events as if the user had entered/leaved the window. And you will end up hating blindly typing key sequences, anyway ;-)